# Exploding coefficients in a Linear Regression Model with single input

Tags: regression, python, linear, gradient-descent, numpy

This is my first post here, so tips are appreciated for future posts!

For homework in my CS course I wanted to build a very simple Linear Regression Model (although this was not explicitly required) to determine slope m and intercept b given inputs with my code being so far:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 110, 500, 1000, 1200, 2500, 7000])  # Independent variable
y = np.array([10, 11, 14, 18, 20, 25, 35])  # Dependent variable

m = 0.5
b = 0.5
lr = 0.0001
epochs = 200

def d_m(y, y_pred, x):
    result = -2 * np.sum(x * (y - y_pred)) / len(y)
    # print(y, y_pred, x, x * (y - y_pred), np.sum(x * (y - y_pred)))
    return result

def d_b(y, y_pred):
    result = -2 * np.sum(y - y_pred) / len(y) 
    return result

def mean_squared_error(y, y_pred):
    result = np.sum(y - y_pred) / len(y)
    return result

def train_model(y, x, m, b, lr, epochs):
    for _ in range(epochs):
        y_pred = m * x + b
        Dm = d_m(y, y_pred, x)
        Db = d_b(y, y_pred)
        m = m - lr * Dm
        b = b - lr * Db
    
    mse = mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)
    return m, b, mse

m, b, mse = train_model(y, x, m, b, lr, epochs)

print(m, b, mse)
```

The problem is now, with the given input and the parameters I chose, either the initial values of m and b don't change at all after the episodes, or they explode upwards too quick. I tried normalizing the input with (x - x.mean()) / x.std(), but I don't know how to get the appropriate m and b rescaled to the original input, because this is what the task asks for.

Any help would be appreciated, because I dont quite understand where I went wrong!

Comment: have you double checked that your derivatives are correct using finite differences?

Comment: I've not heard of that so far, I read up on it a little but I dont really understand how to apply it if theres multiple variables in the derivative sadly

Comment: check the "Multivariate finite differences" section on Wiki. it's easy to make small mistakes which snowball; (for example your MSE is not squared, not that this would affect convergence).

Comment: your mean squred error is not squared.

Comment: I know, sadly that doesn't change the behaviour of the gradients.

Comment: @JohnMadden thanks for the tip, I have to check that some other time I guess, didn't understand that enough yet to implement it myself